# Open pipe with no privileges on windows

Tags: c, windows, pipe, privileges

Is it possible to open a pipe from a process that does not have the `SeChangeNotifyPrivilege` privilege?

I control the creation of the pipe with `CreateNamedPipe` and want to open the pipe in another process with `CreateFile`. I get an access denied error as soon as i remove the `SeChangeNotifyPrivilege`. Is it possible to create the pipe in a way such that other processes do not need this privilege?

**EDIT**: Example

Creating the pipe in Process A:

```
hPipe = CreateNamedPipeW(
    name,                      // pipe name 
    PIPE_ACCESS_INBOUND,       // read/write access 
    PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE |       // message type pipe 
    PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE |   // message-read mode 
    PIPE_WAIT,                // blocking mode 
    PIPE_UNLIMITED_INSTANCES, // max. instances  
    buf_size,                  // output buffer size 
    buf_size,                  // input buffer size 
    0,                        // client time-out 
    &attr);                   // security attribute
```

Security attributes are chosen to allow access to everybody (NULL ACL).

Accessing the pipe in Process B:

```
HANDLE hPipe = CreateFileW(
    name,     // pipe name 
    GENERIC_WRITE,  // write access 
    0,              // no sharing 
    NULL,           // default security attributes
    OPEN_EXISTING,  // opens existing pipe 
    0,              // default attributes 
    NULL);          // no template file
```

Process B has a restricted Access Token with the `SeChangeNotifyPrivilege` privilege disabled. `CreateFileW` returns access denied. When enabling the privilege, opening the pipe works. Note that in my application I cannot give this privilege to Process B because of requirements.

Comment: Please show a [mcve]

Comment: I updated the question

Comment: For the record, Windows pretty much assumes that everyone will have SeChangeNotifyPrivilege.  Disabling it is likely to cause all sorts of problems.

Comment: One possible workaround would be to have another process (depending on the circumstances this might be process A, process B's parent, or perhaps a completely independent process) open the handle and pass it to B via DuplicateHandle.  Awkward, but if you can't find any other solution and can't talk whoever makes the rules into not sabotaging your process for you, it might be the only option. :-)

Comment: Unfortunately duplicating/inheriting handles is also not an option due to the sabotaging rules, it must be a somehow globally accessible pipe. As named pipes are stored under \Device\NamedPipe, I can understand why it is not possible to access this path with a restricted access token. But still, is there no workaround?